# Could not find resource com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EBItemMapper.xml

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

When I use Maven to build the project in the sqlMapConfig.xml file code as follows:

```
  <!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbBrandMapper.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml"/> 
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Tomcat startup will report the error as follow：

```
Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
```

However, when I configured as follows, the Tomcat will not start abnormal
as follow：

```
 <!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbBrandMapper.xml"/>
<!--        <mapper resource="com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml"/>  -->
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

After I check the official document, I am sure that this configuration is no problem.I do not know why the wrong? please tell me.thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IOException: Could not find resource com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml

The error is clear. The file "com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml" is not found. Check your path. Looks like you have a forgotten a forward slash before "com".

Use "/com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml".

Comment: First of all , thank you very much.
I use the eclipse development tools. Hold down Ctrl with the left mouse button click on the configuration /com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EbItemMapper.xml I can visit this file but 
I found my real file is com/rl/ecps/sqlMap/EBItemMapper.xml.If I use this method.that eclipse is insensitive to file name

Comment: @LPGAD. You are welcome. Glad that I could be of help. Feel free to let us know if you have any other questions in future.